# How to change existing image when you click on a JButton in JFrame? (Java)

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

So I'm making a game where I want to change the image of an image that is already on the screen when I click on a JButton, but nothing I tried is working so I'm here to ask help.

This is my code:

```
package frametest;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JPanel totalGUI, player1, buttons;
    JLabel p1a, p1b;
    JButton change1, change2;
    ImageIcon C2 = new ImageIcon("Pictures\\cards\\C2.png");
    ImageIcon SK = new ImageIcon("Pictures\\cards\\SK.png");    
    ImageIcon HJ = new ImageIcon("Pictures\\cards\\HJ.png");

    public JPanel createContentPane(){  
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        totalGUI.setBackground(new Color( 52, 186, 119 ));
        totalGUI.setLayout(null);

        //Speler 1
        JPanel player1 = new JPanel();
        player1.setLocation(240,431);
        player1.setSize(190,110);
        player1.setBackground(new Color( 52, 186, 119 ));
        totalGUI.add(player1);

        JLabel p1a = new JLabel();
        p1a.setIcon(C2);
        p1a.setLocation(0,0);
        player1.add(p1a);
        pack();

        JLabel p1b = new JLabel();
        p1b.setIcon(SK);
        p1b.setLocation(0,20);
        player1.add(p1b);
        pack();

        //Knoppen
        JPanel buttons = new JPanel();
        buttons.setLayout(null);
        buttons.setLocation(700,435);
        buttons.setSize(200,90);
        totalGUI.add(buttons);

        JButton change1 = new JButton("Jack of Hearts");
        change1.setLocation(0,0);
        change1.setSize(200,30);
        change1.addActionListener(this);
        buttons.add(change1);      

        JButton change2 = new JButton("King of Spades");
        change2.setLocation(0,30);
        change2.setSize(200,30);
        change2.addActionListener(this);
        buttons.add(change2);

        totalGUI.setOpaque(true);
        return totalGUI;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getSource() == change1) {
            p1a.setIcon(HJ);
        } else if(e.getSource() == change2 ) {
            p1a.setIcon(SK);
        } 
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Poker Game");

        FrameTest demo = new FrameTest();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.setSize(1000,600);     
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }}
```

It seems I have to write more in this post to be able to post it, but I don't know what to write...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you redeclared your variables inside the method `createContentPane()`.

```
public JPanel createContentPane(){  
        JPanel totalGUI = new JPanel();
        /**/
}
```

should be

```
public JPanel createContentPane(){  
        totalGUI = new JPanel();
        /**/
}
```

You have to do the same for `player1, buttons, p1a, p1b, change1, change2` inside the `createContentPane()` method.

Comment: OH MY GOD THANKS A LOT! I've been stuck on this problem for days and the answer was so simple. Thanks!